# How to retrive Core Data SQL store from Developer's App on the Developer's iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-data

I need a copy of the store that is saved as Core Data sqlite file inside a test app installed on my device.

I know how to get files out of the the  simulator at path: `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[Version]/Applications/[AppID]/Documents`

...but i need get the `.sqlite` file from the app on the device itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the app itself has file sharing built in, you can't access the documents folder from outside the app. It is a security precaution and part of the sandbox.

### Update:

I misunderstood the context of the question. To get files off a developers iPhone, connect the device and open Xcode>Window>Organizer. Select the device in the lefthand pane. In the righthand pane will be a list of applications. Your custom apps will have an arrow next to it. Hit the arrow and you will see "Application Data" hit the down arrow icon and it will let you download the data to folder. That folder will contain the apps Document, Library and tmp folders.

Comment: Okey. Do jailbrake ? Will it help

Comment: I believe jailbreaking resets the phone but I could be wrong. Do you have to recover data from one specific phone? That would be a data recovery task.

Comment: Yes. I create experimental databases before release app. After adding in app store Databases data serve to matching real life data

Comment: I think you mean "Devices & Simulators" under Window menu. Of course, this is likely just a change by apple.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an application specifically for this to distribute to my customers and testers of my applications when they have problems.  [iPhoneRescue](http://priddysoftware.com/software/iPhoneRescue/) is free and allows you to get at all of the backup information in your iPhone; this includes any sqlite files.

All the users have to do is find their device backup, find the application, and then save the application files or just a specific file.  (This does not work if they have encrypted their backups).